# display a list of value in one textarea in struts2

Tags: java, list, jsp, textarea

I'm looking for the best way to put all the objects in a java.util.list in one textarea with a return line for each record.

I don't need to submit the result cause my textarea will be disabled.

For example:
here is the list of persons: {person1,person2,person3}
And i would like that the values appear in the JSP in a textarea like that:

person1.name
person2.name
person3.name
etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a custom getter (i.e. for a "virtual" property) which creates a string from the list as you need it to be and make that property value the content of the text area? (Of course you can also store that string somewhere and manually keep it up to date).

Example:

```
public String getTextAreaContent() {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for( Person p : personlist ) {
    if( sb.length() > 0 ) { //already content in the sb
      sb.append("\n"); //or maybe you'd need a <br>
    }

    sb.append( p.name );
  }

  return sb.toString();
}
```

And in the JSP:

```
<s:property value="textAreaContent"/>
```

Another option might be to use an iterator on the jsp and build the content there, but this would at least yield slightly worse performance due to the higher number of OGNL calls involved.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think about this possibility. I just added the tag <s:textarea id="textAreaContent" name="textAreaContent" ></s:textarea>